# Jquery html: issue with width of a container

Tags: jquery

In a website I'm using fonts from typekit.

Only in safari (Mac and Windows) I have an issue when page is loaded:

[image]

You can note that `h3#superfood-ingredient` has a width of only 3px . After a refresh, the `h3#superfood-ingredient` has the correct width.

Font is taken from typekit, and the code of jquery is the following:

```
var url = site+'/feeds/superfood?id='+id;
        $.ajax({
                method: 'GET',
                url: url,
                dataType: 'json',
                success : function(response)
                {
                    $(jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(response))).each(function()
                    {
                        var ingredient = this.ingredient;
                        var description = this.description;
                        var find_it = this.find_it;
                        $('#superfood-ingredient').html(ingredient);
                        $('#superfood-description').html(description);
                        $('p#superfood-find-it>span').html(find_it);
                    });
                }
        });
```

Comment: Not related to problem but instead of `jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(response))` use just `response`.

Comment: Could you provide a demo in http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @Ultra no, unfortunately I cannot (fonts are not loaded in others domain that mine, TypeKit mandatary)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force it's width with CSS. I know it's bad for internationalization but works:

```
h3#superfood-ingredient { display:inline-block; width:179px; }
```

Comment: I did add for the moment a "width 100%", no problem for my layout. Width 179px, I could have some word more long... By the way I would understand why this problem exists... Thank you btw ;)

Comment: If you position `width:100%;` an `position:absolute;` element, it will stretch 100% of it's relative parent's width; same with height. If parent is 0px wide/tall than it's possible to have "bug" like you have.